# materialize-css select styles display:none are applied to ckeditor dialogues

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor, materialize, django-ckeditor

I am trying to learn the **Django-Python Framework** by building a blog webapp. I am using **Materialize CSS** Framework 1.0.0 for styling. Furthermore for creating posts I use **CKEditor 4**. I want users to be able to add **CodeSnippets**. The CKEditor is in my static directory and is rendered well, BUT I can't choose a language when I open the codesnippet dialog.

[codesnippet dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Waw.jpg)

I found out that the materialize-css library applies **"display: none"** to all select inputs. Materialize is not in my own directory, but I am using **CDN**, so I can't tweak this.

*I tried the following:*

I inspected the element in the Chrome Dev Tool and added in ckeditor/dialog/styles/dialog.css the following:

```
.cke_dialog_ui_input_select { display: block; }
```

Furtheremore at the end of the body tag in my base.html I added:

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('select').css("display","block");
     });
     console.log("display to block");
    </script>                                                                                  
  </body>
```

I also tried this in the above script:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('select').formSelect();                                                                       
  });
```

I break the server and apply **python manage.py runserver** after each change. But again when I check it in Chrome Dev Tool I still see that Materialize is setting the display to none. I found something here
[Drupal - materialize-css select styles are applied to ckeditor dialogues](https://www.drupal.org/project/material_admin/issues/3020150) , but I don't understand it.

The last thing I could think about was changing the **JQuery** event **.ready** to something with **onload**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can give any select a class of `browser-default` to remove it from Materialize styling.

Comment: How do you render the html on the page? `<select class="browser-default"></select>` you can see here, any select with this class will not be subject to materialize styling: https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/bGpexMp

Comment: I changed the script to `<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('select').formSelect({
              classes: "browser-default"
          });
        });
      </script>` , like set here [materializecss-select-options](https://materializecss.com/select.html). But it's not working for the dialog.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. In my own forms it's just working, `class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'category', 'front_image', 'content']

        widgets = {
            'title' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category' : forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'browser-default'}, choices=SUBJECT_CATEGORY),
            'content' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }`

Comment: That not how you set classes on the select, as it says on the docs page: "Classes to be added to the select wrapper element.". I ask you again - how do you render the html on the page?

Comment: In my own forms it's just working, but the dialog (when I click on codesnippet in ckeditor) of CKEditor is rendered as:  `<select id="cke_255_select" class="cke_dialog_ui_input_select" aria-labelledby="cke_256_label">` and then options which are not showing. When I look at my base.html template there is just a div `<div class="django-ckeditor-widget" data-config="{&quot;CodeSnippet&quot;}"</div>` . So in that div is the ckeditor living.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

1. in my static file I added a main.css, so that **static/blog/main.css**

**main.css** :

```
select.cke_dialog_ui_input_select {
  display: block;
}
```

2. I added in the **<head>** section in my **base.html** template the link:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">
```

**AFTER**/**UNDER** the materialize CSS reference links.

3. I cleared my google chrome cache. [Clear Chrome Cache](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

When I now open the codesnippet (red circled), I can choose a language. [Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhIQL.jpg)

Thanks for your help Sean ;p